# How to blur image with react native within a time interval?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, blur

I am new to react native programming. I am having a requirement to blur the image within a certain time. What I have done is a very basic method as you can see in the following code. If someone can give better idea on how to achieve this that would be great. With the following approach even I am having a big issue which is every second my screen gets refreshed. And I believe this will be a performance issue as well.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    setInterval( () => {
      this.setState({
        bgBlured: this.state.bgBlured + 1
      }) 
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.bgBlured)
    return (      
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image 
          source={bg} 
          blurRadius={this.state.bgBlured} />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Can someone help me to sort this out ?